# homework function exercise im stuck

Tags: javascript

Hi im doing some exercise to practice JS and the idea is to create a const with different parts of a PC and using a methods to change a value (in this case the GPU) from 1 to 2 but the thing is in  console log of myPc.addAnotherGpu)`is`undefined` when it should say 2

What am I doing wrong?

```js
// My PC components
const myPc = {
  name: "ASUS_PC",
  components: {
    gpu: 1,
    motherboard: 1,
    ram: 32,
    hdd: 1000,
  },
  newGpu: function(addAnotherGpu) {
    this.components.gpu = addAnotherGpu;
  }
};


console.log("My PC components:", myPc);

console.log("My old GPU:", myPc.components.gpu)

myPc.newGpu(2)

console.log("My new GPUs:", myPc.addAnotherGpu)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing your attempt! May you also edit the question to share what output you want?

Comment: `myPc` has no `.addAnotherGpu` property. It's still `myPc.components.gpu` as in the `console.log()` before.

Answer (score 2):

This line seems off:

```js
console.log("My new GPUs:", myPc.addAnotherGpu)
```

You still need to check for `myPc.components.gpu`. Since that's the member of the object, you are setting with your function.

```js
console.log("My new GPUs:", myPc.components.gpu)
```

Comment: This is just a typo and should be closed as such...

Comment: You are probably right.

Comment: Then why the answer?

Comment: Because when I answered, you didn't comment yet and made me think of it. Technically, my answer isn't incorrect. It's debatable, I guess. But if you are not happy with my answer, feel free to raise a flag.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry what do you mean with "typo"

Comment: @sebasto Typo: _"To make a typographical error"_ - `.addAnotherGpu` makes no sense because there's no such property. It should be `..components.gpu` <- easy to fix "ups, wrong property error" = typo